# Net::OpenTimeout execution expired in Action Mailer Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sendgrid, sucker-punch

I am getting the below error while sending emails from ActionMailer

> ERROR -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob]
>   [a532d442-ad8a-44a9-b13d-a2a3ec9c5bd9] Error performing
>   ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID:
>   a532d442-ad8a-44a9-b13d-a2a3ec9c5bd9) from SuckerPunch(mailers) in
>   30009.94ms: Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired):

This error comes sometimes and sometimes it works. I have the below code in my application.rb

```
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'
require 'resolv-replace'
```

And below in my sucker punch.rb

```
SuckerPunch.shutdown_timeout = 15
```

I am using **Rails 5.1.4** and **sendgrid** for sending emails.

Comment: Can you please add details about smtp settings configuration